# jQuery start page at certain div without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to start the page at certain div without scrolling using `jQuery`?

For now i'm using this code:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.here').offset().top
}, 500);
```

But this, of course, scrolls to that div on page loading, i want it to just load the page straight to that div(if there is a certain cookie set)

Comment: Just a thought: You could set the animation duration to 0 to jump there instantly.

Comment: i've done that but it doesn't jump there :(

Comment: if i completely remove `, 500` it still scrolls :(

Comment: If you remove it completely I think it will fall back to a default duration. Have you tried actually giving it the value 0?

Comment: yes, if i set it to `0` nothing happens when i reload the page, no scroll, no jump :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `animate` to change the scroll position. Just do `$('html, body').scrollTop($('.here').offset().top)`.

Or probably even simpler, just give the desired element an id and then set the `window.location.hash` to be that id.

Comment: Hey @RobinZigmond, this works well in Firefox but it doesn't work in chrome :( what should i do ? :-s

Comment: @emma what isn't working? This seems fine to me in Chrome. Can you share part of your code where I can see that it doesn't work?

Comment: It works now, but i have no clue why @RobinZigmond. X_X maybe there was some cache or something? chrome is a bit strange :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/):

```js
const target = $('.here').offset().top;

window.scrollTo({
    top: target,
    behavior: 'instant'
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 49vh;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

.here {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block here"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Hei @OriDrori, i have no clue what i'm doing wrong but there is no error in my console and yet it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

"*if there is a certain cookie set*"

If you're using any server-side scripting language to get/set that cookie, you could also append the id to the div as a hash to make it jump to that div.

So for example, if my page is

```
....
<div id="somecontent">...</div>
<div id="jumphere">...</div>
<div id="someothercontent">...</div>
...
```

and the url is *http://www.myawesomewebsite.com/page#jumphere*, then in most browsers, your page will jump to that point after load

Answer (score 1):

You can run this javascript when the page loads. It will take you to the specified div with the `id` specified. Take a look at the snippet below:

```js
let boxTop = $("#orange-div").offset().top;
window.scrollTo(0, boxTop);
```

```css
.padding-div {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="padding-div">

</div>

<div id="orange-div" class="box">

</div>

<div class="padding-div">

</div>
```

Comment: Hey @NickParsons, This solution works in firefox but not in chrome, what should i do? :(